# For loop does not run C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

The output is `21` meaning it has entered the `printBoard` function and has exited it. I have tried making a test variable and doing something with it in the for loop, but it didn't do anything, so therefore for some reason the for loop does not execute.

```
#include <iostream>


void printBoard(){
    std::cout << "2";
    for(int i = 0; i == 8;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j == 8;j++){
            std::cout << "| - |";
        }
        std::cout << "| - |" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "1";
}

int main(){
    printBoard();
}
```

Comment: what makes you think that the loop should execute more than zero times? How often do you think it should execute?

Comment: Please read a c++ book for beginners

Comment: Haha I see, it was a silly mistake, I just forgot how for loop logic works, thanks.

Comment: typos are made all the time, thats not a silly mistake. If you like you can call it "silly" that you didn't do anything to find out what your mistake was or to fix it ;) You could have used a debugger for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of the for loop is the condition that needs to be **true** for the loop to execute. `i == 8` is not true (because i is 0), so the loop will never run. You want `i <= 8` if you want to count until 8.

Comment: I'd rather suggest `i < 8`, because `i <=` will cause off-by-one errors if applied blindly, while there is no problem with using `<` everywhere

Comment: @idclev463035818: Indeed. Until C++20 spoils the party with the 3 way operator, `<` is in a sense the natural comparison operator in C++.

Comment: @Batsheba half open intervals are used everywhere. Seeing `<=` in a loop is a surprise, which sometimes is justified, most often it is not

Comment: @idclev463035818: I've never come across a game with a 9x9 board. You are almost certainly correct here. And as such, methinks this answer is incomplete. Downvote time.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in the stopping conditional of the loop (if the conditional evaluates to `false` then the loop terminates). The fix, for an 8 x 8 board, is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8;j++){
```

See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm)